# Terraform, string to list error while counting

Tags: terraform

I am trying to make a Terraform playbook that creates Azure routes through a loop.

The end-goal is the user will type in their destinations in a comma separated list.  For example:

```
Enter route destinations: 0.0.0.0/0,192.168.0.0/16
```

From this variable, the azurerm_route will run through this function and create the routes.

```
variable "destinations" {
  default = "0.0.0.0/0,192.168.0.0/16"
}

resource "azurerm_route" "route" {
  name                    = "route-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name     = "resourcegroup"
  route_table_name        = "table"
  address_prefix          = "${split(",", var.destinations)}[count.index]"
  next_hop_type           = "Internet"
  count                   = "${length(split(",", var.destinations))}"
}
```

However, I am having an issue with counting through the prefix list and I am receiving the following error:

```
* azurerm_route.route[1]: At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL 
expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 1 is 
TypeList) in:

${split(",", var.destinations)}[count.index]

* azurerm_route.route[0]: At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL 
expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 1 is 
TypeList) in:

${split(",", var.destinations)}[count.index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  You have to use the element interpolation.

```
resource "azurerm_route" "route" {
  name                    = "route-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name     = "resourcegroup"
  route_table_name        = "table"
  address_prefix          = "${element(split(",",var.destinations),count.index)}"
  next_hop_type           = "Internet"
  count                   = "${length(split(",",var.destinations))}"
}
```